# Reopen old question to provide good answer

Tags: discussion

I was browsing across questions and I came across [this one](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/4534/20940).

I made a comment about the game [Exploding Kittens](http://explodingkittens.com), and I feel like it should be an answer because the game is specifically marketed as being similar to Russian Roulette and the OP specifically asks about using "dice or cards" and being "kid friendly". As I mentioned in my comment, Exploding Kittens is marked as appropriate for 7+.

My question is: **Should this old question be reopened so a good answer can be provided (for both the OP and others)?**

Answer (score 8):

That question is closed as "Off Topic" because it is asking for game recommendations, which we do not allow. It doesn't matter whether someone has a good game to recommend. That question will stay closed.

Comment: I've seen it asked in just about every off topic for recommendations question in the comments, but never answered, why is there a tag for recommendations if we do not allow recommendations questions?

Comment: The tag exists because there are still questions that have it. They're all closed, but they're still there. People could spend a few days going through and deleting all of them, but the tag can also be useful as another way to communicate that it is off topic, using the tag wiki.

Comment: Unfotunately most users do not read the tag wikis. They barely look at tbe usage info.

Comment: Perhaps se needs a feature to lock out tags kept for posterity to a permissions level then. Or if one exists we should use it here.

Answer (score 3):

To give an answer with a wider scope:

Questions aren't closed to prevent people adding new or updated answers.  Questions are closed because they don't meet the site's criteria and have been deemed unsuitable.  So closed questions simply don't get reopened just to get new answers.

There is another mechanism to affect the ability of users to post answers - Question Protection.  A question may be *protected* by a moderator or trusted user if it has been subject to a number of poor quality answers.  It prevents users with less than 10 reputation *on the site* (i.e. association bonus is ignored) from posting answers.

If you have a new answer that you would like to add to an old question, then go ahead and post it.  This is, after all, what the SE system is all about.